# What does the backward slash (\) do in a format mask?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can't seem to find the answer in Google. Is it in a similar category of symbols like  `$` and `!` or something else entirely?

The formula I found on Google is:

```
=text(A2,"\0.0,,\M")
```

which converts 1500000 to 1.5M.

Comment: could you post an example?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/612471

Comment: @NickSlash im pretty sure that is to do with cell formatting not formulas. I am not aware of any special characteristic assigned to the backslash

Comment: Your title asks about the back-slash's role in an Excel formula but your question has to do specifically with a format mask. Your example of expected output is also wrong in that it does not show the forced leading zero that the supplied example formula would show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your given example (*a format mask*), a backslash acts as an escape sequence. Basically, it is equivalent to wrapping the next character in double quotations. This is done to get the literals for `0` and `M`, since there are a number of characters that have special meanings unless you use an escape sequence.

Date-formatting and time-formatting characters `(a, c, d, h, m, n, p, q, s, t, w, y, /,` and `:)`, the numeric-formatting characters `(#, 0, %, E, e, comma, and period)`, and the string-formatting characters `(@, &, <, >, and !)`all must be escaped to be accessed literally.

---

*Due to the slight confusion as to what context you don't understand `\` in, I have added a bit of additional information.*

## In cell formatting:

The backslash `\` is used to escape special characters, like a colon.
For instance, if you wanted

```
100 : 1
```

since the colon is a special character, you would have to use `\` (*an escape sequence*) to access it as a literal, like this:

```
100 \: 1
```

which outputs `100 : 1` as desired.

Another example of use would be the `\n` VB newline character (different language obviously), which will escape to a new line in your output. In this case, the `\` escapes the literal of the key `n` to access the special constant `vbNewLine`.

It follows in many programming languages, `\` followed by something is often  an **escape sequence**, and used to avoid or access a special characterization of a given key or character.

## In VBA:

It is also worth noting that in VBA, the backslash character can be used to force an evaluation of the integer equivalent of a quotient, for instance:

```
100\33 = Int(100/33)
```

This is an often overlooked way to divide as well as round down to an integer in a single step.

## In workbooks:

One of the options to create a range name in your workbook is to precede the name of your desired range name with a backslash. For instance, a valid range name would be `\HLF1`

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in detail! It's the first time I've come across a format mask, the additional info helps too. Had a couple of reads before I got it but I think I do now.